# Inconsistent output of cp -v command between machines

Tags: coreutils

On two different machines I maintain, `cp -v`'s output is different. On one box, both src and dest are quoted, on another box, the first quote around both src and dest is a backtick:

Box one (recent userland, coreutils 8.32):

```
cp -v foo foo2
'foo' -> 'foo2'
```

Box two (very old userland, coreutils 6.7):

```
cp -v foo foo2
`foo' -> `foo2'
```

I first thought it had to do with the shell, but that doesn't seem to matter. I tried looking back to 6.7 in git, but I cannot seem to figure out why one machine uses all single quotes, and the other uses backticks.

I do not have the option to test a newer cp binary on the machine with the old userland. It's an embedded NAS system.

Comment: What's your locale on these systems (output of `locale`)?

Comment: Both have LANG set to en_US.UTF-8